# Unable to run a Laravel Artisan command with parameters using Symfony process

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, symfony-process

I'm trying to start a process with Symfony in my Laravel app on my shared hosting server that will call an Artisan command with parameters like so:

```
$process = new Process(['/usr/local/bin/php', base_path('artisan'), 'queue:work --stop-when-empty']);
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->start();
```

This does not work as I get:

```
ERROR: Command "queue:work --stop-when-empty" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
    queue:batches-table
    queue:clear
    queue:failed
    queue:failed-table
    queue:flush
    queue:forget
    queue:listen
    queue:monitor
    queue:prune-batches
    queue:prune-failed
    queue:restart
    queue:retry
    queue:retry-batch
    queue:table
    queue:work {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException(code: 0): Command \"queue:work --stop-when-empty\" is not defined.
```

The problem is with the parameter `--stop-when-empty` as the command runs succesfully wthout it. How can I pass this parameter to the command ?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use `Artisan::call` ?

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process adds quotes around each array value that you pass in. Right now, it's attempting to run

```
"exec '/usr/local/bin/php' '/your/path/to/artisan' 'queue:work --stop-when-empty'"
```

So by adding quotes around the whole string, it's treating `'queue:work --stop-when-empty'` as a single command, instead of a command and option. Separate out the command so that it will quote it properly

```
$process = new Process(['/usr/local/bin/php', base_path('artisan'), 'queue:work', '--stop-when-empty']);
```